# Return Largest sum in a List based on a Condition

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to ignore '0' when I have 1,0,1 pattern  in my list and return the largest sum of list

Examples:

```
[1,0,1]              => returns  2 (0 is ignored and sum would be 1+1)
[1,0,0,1]            => in this case there is no 101 pattern I have only 
                       [**1**,0,0,1] - returns sum as 1
                       [1,0,0,**1**]  - returns sum as 1 
                       so Final oputput is 1  
[1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]    => returns  5,( in this case there are two "1,0,1" pattern  

   Scenario 1: [*1,0,1*,1,0,1,1,1] => if Highlighted pattern is taken into 
                                      account and '0' is ignored then resultant list will be [1,1,1,0,1,1,1]       and sum would 3 (1+1+1)
   Scenario 2:[1,0,1,*1,0,1*,1,1] => if Highlighted pattern is taken into 
                                       account and '0' is ignored then resultant list will be [1,0,1,1,1,1,1] 
                                       and sum would be 5 (1+1+1+1+1)
 The largest sum in between 3 (Scenario 1) and 5 (Scenario 2)  is 5 so the 
    final output is 5
```

So Far Tried :

```
def sum(days: List[bool]) -> int:
    count=1
    l=[]
    d=[]
    if(len(days)==0): return 0
    if( sum(days)==0): 
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(days)):        
            if(i+1==len(days) and len(l) > 0 ):
                print(l)
                return max(l)
            elif i+1==len(days): return count
            
            if( days[i]==days[i+1] and days[i]==1):
                count=count+1     
            else:
                l.append(count)               
                count=1

print(sum([1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1] )) --- (currently Prints 3 (1+1+1) since I haven't implemented for 1,0,1 pattern check)
```

The above code returns max sum I haven't yet implemented for pattern check and returning largest sum and don't know how to proceed. If anyone has easier ways to solve this problem let me know. I highly appreciate it

Comment: Can you please check now

Comment: What is meant by „list will be [1,1,1,0,1,1,1]  and sum would 3 (1+1+1)“? Why is the sum 3 instead of 6? Are you looking for the length of the longest sequence of 1s?

Comment: For this case `[1,0,0,1]` why is the answer `1` when there is no pattern of `1 0 1`. This is just one case, other examples are also not clear. Read it again, as if your new to the same problem. If people are not able to understand your question, it would get downvoted and also closed, so do explain in it in depth.

Comment: @PadmajaKattamuri IIUC this might be what you're trying to accomplish: For a list of length `n` search for every pattern of `[1, 0, 1]` and then `pop` the middle `0` and count the max amounts of consecutive `1` in the new list. Return the maximum number of consecutive `1` that can be created using only a single `pop`.

Comment: YEs @HampusLarsson you are right

Answer (score 1):

it's quite lengthy, and could be cleaner, however I think that this will do what you want:

```
from itertools import groupby

def popsum(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 2:
        return lst.count(1)

    # Look for the indexes of the pattern we want to search through
    idxes = [idx for idx in range(1,len(lst)-1) if lst[idx-1:idx+2] == [1,0,1]]
    
    # If no indexes are there, calculate with the original list
    if not idxes:
        grp = [list(i) for _, i in groupby(lst)]
        return max([len(i) if 1 in i else 0 for i in grp])

    # If there are indexes, calculate each iterations max-length
    iterations = []
    for idx in idxes:
        # Because list.pop changes the list "in place"
        # we first copy the list, so that we're not
        # changing the original
        l = lst.copy() 
        # pop the zero in the new list
        l.pop(idx) 

        # Gather a list of all connected groups of 1 or 0
        grp = [list(i) for _, i in groupby(l)]
        # If 0 in the group, zero it out, else calculate len
        iterations.append(max([len(i) if 1 in i else 0 for i in grp]))

    return max(iterations)

print(popsum([1, 0, 1]))  # 2
print(popsum([1, 0, 0, 1]))  # 1
print(popsum([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]))  # 5
```